# Controlling behavior of LegendMarkerSize

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending, fonts, plot-themes

I notice a strange behavior for the `LegendMarkerSize` while trying to adjust its size.

```
ListPlot[
  {Around[2.2`, 1.1]},
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 11},
  PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[
      PointLegend[{"Plot"},
        Spacings -> {.5},
        LegendMarkerSize -> 6,
        LegendLayout -> "Row"
      ], 
      {0.7, .87}
    ],
  Sequence[PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Medium]
]
```

[image]

As long as I keep `LegendMarkerSize` a bigger number it's showing the circle correctly, however, as I decrease it the circle seems to be shadowed by white color or the shape is not circled anymore. Any idea what could be wrong?

---

EDIT:

Apart from the above problem which is there in versions `12.0,12.2,12.3.1,13.0.1`, there is an additional problem with the
combination of  `PlotMarkers, BaseStyle, Font`

Here is a real-life example with `13.0` on Linux:

```
dataN1[NN_] := 2/3 (-(2/NN^3)-2/(1+NN)^3-2 PolyGamma[2,NN])+20/9 (1/NN^2+1/(1+NN)^2-2 PolyGamma[1,NN])+112/27 (-((1+2 NN)/(NN+NN^2))-2 (EulerGamma+PolyGamma[0,NN]))-328/81-4/(3 (NN+NN^2))+(5 \[Pi]^2)/9+(28 Zeta[3])/9;
dataN2={{Around[-8.517476743713672, 0.0876127634868302]},{Around[-12.9100490376823, 0.09859356325470861]},{Around[-15.726165339752113`, 0.10506181651744786`]},{Around[-17.82489909180393, 0.10953184648122824`]},{Around[-19.495070617689237`, 0.1129752084056374]}};
XValue={2,4,6,8,10};
plotDataN2=TemporalData[{dataN2}, {XValue}];

p1=Plot[dataN1[NN],{NN,0.3,11},
    PlotStyle->{{Red}},
    PlotTheme->"Detailed",
    PlotLegends->Placed[LineLegend[{"1"},Spacings->{0.25},LegendMarkerSize->13],{0.8,.75}]];

p2=ListPlot[plotDataN2, 
        PlotRange->{{1.5,11},{-20.5,-5.0}},
        (*PlotMarkers\[Rule]Automatic,*)
        (*PlotMarkers\[Rule]{{"\[FilledCircle]",11}},*)
        IntervalMarkers->"Bars",
        IntervalMarkersStyle->Thickness[0.004],
        PlotLegends->Placed[PointLegend[{"2"},Spacings->{0.25},LegendMarkerSize->6],{0.8,.55}]
        (*BaseStyle\[Rule]{FontFamily\[Rule]"Latin Modern Roman",FontSize\[Rule]15,Bold}*)];
Show[{p1,p2}]
```

1. Without `PlotMarkers,BaseStyle`:
   [image]

Nothing wrong here, I just want to make the markers bigger!

2. With `PlotMarkers->Automatic,` turned on:
   [image]

Look that the markers are now completely distorted!

3. With `PlotMarkers->{{"\[FilledCircle]",11}},`
   [image]

I get bigger marker but now legendmarker is distorted.

4. With `PlotMarkers->{{"\[FilledCircle]",11}},` & `BaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Latin Modern Roman",FontSize->10,Bold}`,
   [image]

The marker in the legend has same problem as before but now the plot is wrong since the plot-markers are shifted down!! Now this I figured out  due to this particular font `Latin Modern Roman`. If I change that to anything else, it is fine.

Note that the Legend Marker problem is there as long as I keep the `LegendMarkerSize->5` a smaller value like `5,6`. If I change that to a bigger value, say `10`, then it is fine.

Conclusion:

1. `PlotMarkers->Automatic` has some bug in showing the markers.
2. `PlotMarkers->{{"\[FilledCircle]",11}},` is fine until one tries to set a smaller `LegendMarkerSize->5`.
3. `BaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Latin Modern Roman"}` has a serious bug since it plots incorrectly. Not sure if this font is supported by Mathematica.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on `V13.1`. Which version are you using?

Comment: I tried 12.0, 12.3.1, 13.0.1 and it exists in all of them!

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try to find one of those versions and check it out :)

Comment: @bmf, unfortunately, I do not have `13.1`, but I provided more examples of these. If these are not a problem in `13.1`, then I am happy :)

Comment: @bmf I have installed 13.1 and I see the same problem as the original post. Could you elaborate what you did extra apart from taking my very first code and just doing copy,paste and run? Just look at the Legend carefully!

Comment: I am attaching a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzFEB.jpg). I cannot spot any white shadows or shapes not circled. As you see, it's just the code from the OP and I just stretched out the graph to make it more visible

Comment: In your screenshot, I see the problem. 1. Please look at the right side of the circle in the plot (you have to zoom in a bit on your plot). 2. But I wanted to draw attention to the Legend which should also be a `FilledCircle` and in your picture, it is very small, but still, if you zoom that you will see it is not a circle. I am referring to the Legend which in this is labeled as Plot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137794/discussion-between-babayaga-and-bmf).